# Cannot execute Python script as a job in Jenkins

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, jenkins

I'm trying to execute a Python script which uses selenium as a job in Jenkins but getting the below error

```
    17:45:55 Started by timer
    17:45:55 Running as SYSTEM
    17:45:55 Building in workspace /Users/it/.jenkins/workspace/crawler
    17:45:55 [crawler] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/t2/sk1vw_mn7mz7ncjw75lzh7r40000gn/T/jenkins8733501635454851045.sh
    17:45:55 + export PYTHONPATH=/Users/it
    17:45:55 + PYTHONPATH=/Users/it
    17:45:55 + cd /Users/it
    17:45:55 + python3 crawler_continious_execution_1.py
    17:45:56 Traceback (most recent call last):
    17:45:56   File "crawler_continious_execution_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    17:45:56     from selenium import webdriver 
    17:45:56 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
    17:45:56 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
    17:45:56 Finished: FAILURE
```

Even if i have installed the SELENIUM module,

```
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % pip3 install selenium           
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.8)
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ %
```

**I have searched google and other stack threads and do as below, but none has worked and is giving the below results.Can anyone please help me to resolve this.**

```
Last login: Wed Apr 15 11:08:19 on ttys000
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % sudo su jenkins 
Password:
su: unknown login: jenkins
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % sudo su -jenkins
su: illegal option -- j
usage: su [-] [-flm] [login [args]]
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % whoami
it
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % su: unknown login: jenkins

zsh: command not found: su:
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
Password:
su: illegal option -- s
usage: su [-] [-flm] [login [args]]
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ %
```

The user which i created on Jenkins installations is jenkins_admin and the Mac user is "IT".

**Have tried many ways but couldn't able to install SELENIUM as JENKINS  user. As you can see selenium is installed but via Jenkins it is showing "Module Not Found Error", IF someone can help on this it will be of great help.**

```
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % whoami
it
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % sudo su jenkins
Password:
su: unknown login: jenkins
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % su jenkins
Password:
su: Sorry
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % su jenkins
Password:
su: Sorry
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % sudo jenkins
Running from: /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins/2.220/libexec/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
2020-04-16 20:50:37.553+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @999ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
2020-04-16 20:50:37.766+0000 [id=1] INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2020-04-16 20:50:37.823+0000 [id=1] WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2020-04-16 20:50:37.934+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.25.v20191220; built: 2019-12-20T17:00:00.294Z; git: a9729c7e7f33a459d2616a8f9e9ba8a90f432e95; jvm 1.8.0_242-b08
2020-04-16 20:50:38.600+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2020-04-16 20:50:38.730+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2020-04-16 20:50:38.731+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2020-04-16 20:50:38.735+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2020-04-16 20:50:39.477+0000 [id=1] INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/root/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
2020-04-16 20:50:45.963+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@5e3f861{Jenkins v2.220,/,file:///private/var/root/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/root/.jenkins/war}
2020-04-16 20:50:45.980+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStop: Stopped ServerConnector@1e67b872{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-04-16 20:50:45.981+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#stopScavenging: node0 Stopped scavenging
2020-04-16 20:50:45.982+0000 [id=1] INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextDestroyed: Shutting down a Jenkins instance that was still starting up
java.lang.Throwable: reason
    at hudson.WebAppMain.contextDestroyed(WebAppMain.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ContextHandler.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ServletContextHandler.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.stopContext(ContextHandler.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.stopContext(ServletContextHandler.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopContext(WebAppContext.java:1415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStop(ContextHandler.java:980)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStop(ServletContextHandler.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop(WebAppContext.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at winstone.Launcher.shutdown(Launcher.java:311)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:202)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:362)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Main._main(Main.java:375)
    at Main.main(Main.java:151)
2020-04-16 20:50:46.005+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStop: Stopped w.@5e3f861{Jenkins v2.220,/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/var/root/.jenkins/war}
Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:543)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 1 more
2020-04-16 20:50:46.016+0000 [id=1] INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Jetty shutdown successfully
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:191)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:362)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Main._main(Main.java:375)
    at Main.main(Main.java:151)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:189)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:220)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
    ... 14 more
2020-04-16 20:50:46.018+0000 [id=1] SEVERE  winstone.Logger#logInternal: Container startup failed
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:220)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:189)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:191)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:362)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Main._main(Main.java:375)
    at Main.main(Main.java:151)
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % whoami
it
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ % python -m pip install -U selenium

Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.8)
it@rgits-Mac-mini ~ %
```

Comment: can you print the error after you added selenium module?

Comment: @LeonidasMenendez The script is running fine if executed in TERMINAL or executed in PYTHON IDLE or Atom.This is showing only if i try to execute it via JENKINS.

Comment: Ok, try to run either with sudo or su but not both

Comment: @LeonidasMenendezTried it but no luck,its not working.Updated the output above.If you can help.

Comment: The last error message is not even related to python, the error is when it tries to start up  java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46735, check firewall, check if another instance is not running

Comment: @LeonidasMenendez That was a temporary issue,now when i type sudo jenkins it is not coming,Can you guide me how can i install selenium and make it run via jenkins? When i try to install selenium it is saying the requirement is already satisfied.